# use object of class in a model in another class angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my project I have two classes in models part that want to use object of one of them in another. One of the class is:

```
export class ConditionPerson {
    marriedStatus: number;
    familyNum: number;
    pet: number;
    describtion: string;
}
```

I want to use object of this class in the class below:

```
 import {ConditionPerson } from './ConditionPerson ';

 export class Property{
    condition : ConditionPerson ;
 }
```

now I want to use the condition property in another class:

```
import {Property} from '../models/Property';
export class AddPropertyComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(public:property: Property){}

if (this.addPropertyPage2.selectedStatus) {
    if (this.addPropertyPage2.selectedStatus != null && typeof this.addPropertyPage2.selectedStatus === 'string') {
        this.property.condition.marriedStatus= +this.addPropertyPage2.selectedVazTaahol;
    } 
    else {
           this.property.conditon.marriedStatus= this.addPropertyPage2.selectedStatus.id;
    }
  }
}
```

here in the else of if when it assigns id to property.condition.marriedStatus says:  **Cannot set property 'condition' of undefined**
what should I do to fix this issue?
Thank you for helping in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the property object

```
 this.property = new property();
```

Comment: thank you for reply. You mean in AddPropertyComponent?

Comment: wherever you're using

Answer (score 0):

First, don't inject a property just declare it:

```
constructor(public:property: Property){} -> public property: Property
```

You miss an i on condition:

```
   this.property.condition.marriedStatus= this.addPropertyPage2.selectedStatus.id;
```

And finally, you didn't initialize `Property` so when you try to affect a value, it gives you the error.

```
export class Property {
  condition: ConditionPerson = { marriedStatus: 0, familyNum: 0, pet: 0, describtion: '' };

}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rgejjn)